# Microservice - keep each sub service in a separate git repository or use a single git repository?

Tags: java, git, microservices

As my microservie project grows, I want some suggestion on how to organize the microservice repo.

**Project layout:**

- xxx-parent/

  - gates/

    - zuul/
    - gateway/
  - configs/

    - config-server/
    - config-files/
  - registers/

    - eureka/
  - apps/

    - user-service/
    - wallet-service/
    - order-service/
    - ...

The parent and 2nd levels are maven pom projects, the 3rd levels are packaged as jar.

**Options:**

1. Each sub module in all 3 levels as a separate git repo.
   This is what I do now, it's easy to work with CI/CD like jenkins.
   But as projects grow, to get the whole project, need to clone many times.
2. Whole project as a single git repo.
   Easy to clone, but coupled in CI/CD or task assignment, also easy to get git conflicts.
3. parent as a repo, each 2nd level and its 3rd levels as a repo.
   This is a trade off for 1 and 2.

How do you do this in your projects?

Comment: Just stick to what you are doing right now. Each service isolated from rest by having their own repository without any binding of any kind like parent-pom etc.

Comment: That's what I prefer, though I had saw both option (1) and (2) in production.

Comment: If you have any parent project or parent-pom with some dependencies then that means you are binding the version of some libraries into your microservices. We had this setup in very early days of our microservices journey 3-4 years back. Fortunately we got rid of them quite fast. If you have limited number of microservices (10-20) easy cloning could be a concern but usually the companies I saw and worked for never stop before having couple of hundreds of microservices. So easy cloning is never an issue to consider.

Comment: @cool Usually I would define some common library, as `<dependencyManagement>` usually, in the top parent pom project for code reuse & easy refactor, that would be an issue later in your experience ?

Comment: Yes. We had a similar setup initially. And it looked fine at that time as we had 12 microservices in total and we were able to manage all of them with a team of 3-4 guys. But even in that case it caused some issues. If you change anything in parent pom most likely you should change the version of all of your child microservices then test and release them. I would highly recommend focusing more on isolation instead of code reuse.

Comment: @cool Ok, as I understand you mean the 1st level parent better be as static as it can be, and better only contain things that rarely change when possible, and the rule may apply to the 2nd level parents as well, with lower stringency.